# How to resolve type safety objections to global setting/event registry?

Tags: java, events, design-patterns, application-settings

I'm working on a client’s Java application with multiple projects and plugins. They have a very brittle design because sharing any information across these division involves some god classes instantiating and registering classes that implement specific interfaces. The interfaces proliferate unchecked and often contain contract methods that no client requires.

In an effort to decouple everything, I have proposed a couple of clearinghouse objects that handle “settings” and “events”. Any class can request a setting, specifying the type of setting from an enumeration and the type of value expected. Any class can register a setting source that implements an interface defining how to get that setting (e.g. whether the network is available by checking some variable in some class), but more often I can completely separate some variable from the original class and it floats for eternity as an anonymous SettingSource that just accepts and publishes some setting value.

```
//code from caller requesting the setting value
long netID = Setting.GetLongSetting(Setting.Type.NetworkID);

//one of those self-defined settings
Setting.RegisterLongSource(Setting.Type.NetworkID, new LongSource() {
  private long myID=-1;

  @Override
  public long getValue() {
    return myID;
  }

  @Override
  public void setValue(long l) {
    myID = l;
  }

  @Override
  public Setting.Type getType() {
    return Setting.Type.NetworkID;
  }
});
```

The events are registered in a similar way with an EventArg object borrowed heavily from C#.

```
//code from an event generator
Events.Event(Event.Type.MessageReceived, new ObjectEventArg(messageInstance));

//An anonymous event listener that expects a message object and passes it to a method for processing
Events.RegisterListener(Event.Type.MessageReceived, new Event.Listener() {
  @Override
  public void HandleEvent(Event.Type type, EventArg e) {
    if(type!=Event.Type.MessageReceived)
    {
       try
       {
         Message m = (Message) ((ObjectEventArgs)e).value;
         if(m!=null)
         {
           this.handleMessage(m);
         }
         else
         {
           //error 3
         }
       }
       catch
       {
         //error 2
       }
    }
    else
    {
      //error 1
    }
  }
});
```

There are some problems with these designs and my clients are asking me to consider something that has more compile-time safety. For example there are three opportunities for errors in the events. It should be impossible for an event listener to get an event type for which it didn't register (error 1), but I should at least check. There is no guarantee that the EventArg type will be the right kind or that the object passed in the ObjectEventArg will match expectations (error 2). There is no guarantee that the passed reference isn't null (error 1). All of this leaves so very much up to the good behavior of the code that cannot be guaranteed at compile time. For that matter, someone could try to create settings for time that accept a string instead of a long and who to say which is right?

What could I do to improve this design, avoid some of the unknowns, and provide that compile-time guarantee?

-------------EDIT---------------
Based on @Jason Albano's answer I could rewrite my solution more like this.

```
//Settings now return a defined type; It could still be null or the wrong type was registered
//if I go all the way with his solution I won't need to cast, but I will have one register/get method for each type.
NetworkIDSetting netID = (NetworkIDSetting) Setting.GetSetting(Setting.Type.NetworkID);

//I can still create a self-defined setting
class NetworkIDSetting() {
  private long myID=-1;

  public long getValue() {
    return myID;
  }

  public void setValue(long l) {
    myID = l;
  }

  @Override
  public Setting.Type getType() {
    return Setting.Type.NetworkID;
  }
}

//i'm less certain how to create a setting that is bound more tightly to another class.
abstract class ScreenWidthSetting {
  public abstract int getWidth();

  //set width is not allowed in this case

  @Override
  public Setting.Type getType() {
    return Setting.Type.ScreenWidth;
  }
}

//then instantiate in the required class
Setting.RegisterLongSource(new ScreenWidthSetting() {
  @Override
  public int getWidth() {
    this.getScreen().getWidth();
  }
});

//definition of an event class
class MessageReceivedEvent {
  public Message myMessage;
  public MessageReceivedEvent(Message m) {
    myMessage = m;
  }

  @Override
  public Event.Type getEventType() {
    return Event.Type.MessageReceived;
  }
}

//code from an event generator
Events.Event(new MessageReceivedEvent(messageInstance));

//I can still create an anonymous event listener with many more guarantees
//again, if I go the whole way I will have a multiplicity of very similar methods
Events.RegisterListener(Event.Type.MessageReceived, new Event.MessageListener() {
  @Override
  public void HandleEvent(MessageEvent e) {
     Message m = e.myMessage;
     if(m!=null)
     {
       this.handleMessage(m);
     }
     else
     {
       //error 3 is still unavoidable
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintaining type safety is precisely what the [Visitor Pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/visitor) is designed for.

The Visitor Pattern separates the operations performed on objects from the objects themselves. In this case, the operations are the handlers and the objects are the events. This pattern works on the principle of [double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch), where the behavior of a method call varies by the object on which the method is called and the arguments supplied to the method.

In the case of handlers and events, we can create the following:

```
public interface Handler {
    void handle(EventA a);
    void handle(EventB b);
}

public interface Event {
    void accept(Handler handler);
}

public class EventA implements Event {

    @Override
    public void accept(Handler handler) {
        handler.handle(this);
    }
}

public class EventB implements Event {

    @Override
    public void accept(Handler handler) {
        handler.handle(this);
    }
}
```

It may look tedious to keep implementing the `accept` method in each `Event` concrete class with the same `handler.handle(this)` body, but that is the key to the pattern. The `this` reference maintains the type of the class making the call. So, for the `EventA` class, when `accept` gets called, the call to `handler.handle(this)` will result in `Handler#handle(EventA a)` being called. Likewise, calling `accept` on a object of `EventB` will result in `Handler#handle(EventB b)` being called.

Comment: Okay, this is something to consider. I hadn't considered this from a Visitor perspective, but the solution I described in my question does use double dispatch. The anonymous Event.Listener or Setting.Source has methods to HandleEvent, SetValue, and GetValue. Those are dispatched by the Event or Setting class when an event or setting request takes place.

Comment: My problem with type safety may be solved by your approach where each Event is a distinct type. In your solution you have and EventA and an EventB. Each of those distinct types probably has definitions for event parameters as well as the implicit definition of the type of event. If I define many event classes and event listener types I could register them with more type safety. Does this really solve my problem?

Comment: I could guarantee that a given event requires a specific type of EventArg. C# does that. My solution does not. Maybe I should.
I still couldn't guarantee that the dispatched event doesn't have a null reference. Maybe no one can.
I could define time as an event that has either or both data versions.

I'm pretty happy that this would work but there is a TON of extra code for each new event type. I'm open to other solutions.